# I am unable to POST a List<T> using knockout.js to my MVC ActionMethod?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

In MVC, I am passing a ViewModel to my View page.

The ViewModel consists of a few properties and a List of connected boards, where  is another ViewModel.

In the View, I create a view model and ensure they are observable and the list of boards is an observable array.

I use Ajax to load the boards depending on the selected value of a drop down, and bind it to a table.

It works pretty great except that the list of boards is not POST'ed back to my HttpPost action method. The other plain string or int variables POST back fine.

The two ViewModels:

```
public class ManufacturingJobcardViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SelectedDevice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public List<ManufacturingBoardsDeviceModel> Boards { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
}

public class ManufacturingBoardsDeviceModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Serial Number")]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "From")]
    public int FromNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "To")]
    public int ToNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Relevant Part of the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateManufacturingGui", "Jobcard", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "manufactureForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div>
            <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>SerialNumber</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
            </tr>

            <tbody data-bind="foreach: Boards">
               <tr>
                   <td data-bind="text: SerialNumber"></td>
                   <td>@Html.TextBox("quantity", "", new { data_bind = "value:Quantity", @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @min = 1 })</td>
                    <td data-bind="text: FromNumber"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: ToNumber"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-wider" />
</div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    getBoards();

    $('#Devices').change(function () {
        getBoards();
    });

    window.viewModel = new CreateManufacturingViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel);

});

function Board(serialNumber, qty, from) {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable();
    self.SerialNumber = serialNumber;
    self.Quantity = ko.observable(qty);
    self.FromNumber = ko.observable(from);
    self.ToNumber = ko.computed(function () {
        return parseInt(self.FromNumber()) + parseInt(self.Quantity()) - 1;
    }, this);
}

function CreateManufacturingViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Customer = ko.observable();
    self.Quantity = ko.observable();
    self.Boards = ko.observableArray();

    self.addBoard = function (serialNumber, qty, fromNumber) {
        self.Boards.push(new Board(serialNumber, qty, fromNumber));
    }

    self.setQuantity = function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.boards(), function (board) {
            board.quantity($('#quantity').val());
        });
    }
}

function getBoards() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetBoards", "Jobcard", null)',
        data: { SelectedModel: $('#Devices').val() },
    }).done(function (data) {

        $(data).each(function (index, element) {
            window.viewModel.addBoard(element.SerialNumber, element.Quantity, element.FromNumber);
        });

    }).error(function (ex) {
        alert("Error");
    });
}
```

The code seems to work correctly as all the boards and the correct data is show, but when I click the POST button the Boards variable is null.

I have tried adding the boards in the ajax success function by using

```
window.viewModel.Boards.fromJS(data);
```

but that does not display any lines at all.

I am extremely new to knockout.js so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is what I am trying:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Boards">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: FromNumber">
                <input data-bind="attr: { name: 'Boards[' + $index + '].FromNumber', value: FromNumber }" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
            </td>    
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[data-bind='attr: { name: 'Boards[' + $index + '].FromNumber', value: FromNumber }']
```

EDIT 2:

Got this working by changing my button from type submit to type button and calling my ActionMethod by Ajax:

```
$('#btnCreate').off().on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateManufacturingGui", "Jobcard", null)',
        data: ko.toJSON(viewModel),            
    }).success(function (data) {
        window.location.replace('@Url.Action("Home", "Jobcard", null)');
    });
});
```

I would like to get it working by direct submit but for now this will suffice.

EDIT 3:

Got it working by doing this:

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: Boards">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind="text: Id, attr: { name: 'Boards[' + $index() + '].Id' }"
                           class="form-control" type="hidden" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind="value: SerialNumber, attr: { name: 'Boards[' + $index() + '].SerialNumber' }"
                           class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind="value: Quantity, attr: { name: 'Boards[' + $index() +'].Quantity' }" 
                           class="form-control" type="number" min=1 />
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input data-bind="value: FromNumber, attr: { name: 'Boards[' + $index() +'].FromNumber' }"
                           class="form-control" type="text" />
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input data-bind="value: ToNumber, attr: { name: 'Boards[' + $index() +'].ToNumber' }"
                           class="form-control" type="text"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to name attribute in input filed, intend of @Html.TextBox use input HTML tag with name attribute data binding with proper index.

For List during HttpPost back should be like name="Boards[RowIndex].PropertyName".

Remove data-bind="text: FromNumber" from "td" tag.

Note: "name" attribute is mandatory for Form Submit. Index value should start form Zero.

```
<input data-bind="value: Id, attr: { name: 'Boards[' + $index() + '].Id' }" 
class="form-control" type="hidden" />

<input data-bind="value: Quantity, attr: { name: 'Boards[' + $index() + 
'].Quantity' }" class = "form-control" type="number" min = 1 />
```

If Borads.length is 2 and required Id and Quantity field alone during HttpPost then following output after KnockoutJs binding should be like,

```
<input name="Boards[0].Id" type="hidden" ... />
<input name="Boards[0].Quantity" type="number" ... />

<input name="Boards[1].Id" type="hidden" ... />
<input name="Boards[1].Quantity" type="number" ... />
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/)

Please let us know in case of any issues / concerns.

Comment: Do you mean I need to change the tables's tbody data-bind code?

Comment: @Neill : Yes. Use <input data-bind="name: 'Boards[' + $index + '].Quantity'" type="text"  
data_bind="value:Quantity" class = "form-control" type="number" min = 1 />  Intend of Html.TextBox.

Comment: @Neill : Only for input or hidden fields. Note for now Quantity value only will be coming during HttpPost. If you need any other value during form HttpPost, need to add some input or hidden field.  Followed by  data-bind="name: 'Boards[' + $index + '].PropertyName'"

Comment: I have tried the code you supplied, but the variable is still null in the POST

Comment: Please see my Edit to see if I am on the right track. We are closing up shop in a short while for 3 weeks, so I might not respond for a while.

Comment: @Neill : Update the answer (data-bind) with a Demo link

Comment: @Neill : remove data-bind="text: FromNumber" from "td" tag.

Comment: Please see Edit 3 for solution that working with form submit. Thanks

Comment: @Neill : WC :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the previous answer has the correct approach but the bindings aren't quite right. You need the use the attr binding like this

```
<input data-bind="attr: { name: 'Boards[' + $index + '].Id', value: Id }" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
<input data-bind="attr: { name: 'Boards[' + $index + '].Quantity', value: Quantity }" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
```